# <li> not recognising php foreach loop (possibly including JS)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-lists

First I realise I'm talking about an external framework but please hear me out as I think it may be more of an html php issue (possibly JS). I am trying to incorporate this horizontal timeline into my web page as a school project:

https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/

I am trying to print out results I got from an array. I am converting the datetime format to the same that is taken in.

Their method is as follows:

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#0" data-date="16/01/2014" class="selected">16 Jan</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/2014">28 Feb</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/04/2014">20 Mar</a></li>
  <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/05/2014">20 May</a></li>
  ............
</ol>
```

While mine looks like this:

```html
<ol>
  <?php foreach ($mile2[ "milestones"] as $key=>$value) { if ($key != 0) { ?>
  <li>
    <a href="#0" data-date="<?=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($mile2['milestones'][$key]['start_time']['date']));?>">
      <?=d ate( 'd M', strtotime($mile2[ 'milestones'][$key][ 'start_time'][ 'date']));?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <?php } else{ ?>
  <li>
    <a href="#0" data-date="<?=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($mile2['milestones'][$key]['start_time']['date']));?>" class="selected">
      <?=d ate( 'd M', strtotime($mile2[ 'milestones'][$key][ 'start_time'][ 'date']));?>
    </a>
  </li>
  <?php }} ?>
</ol>
```

The outputs are very different, this is a link to the demo https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html.

And this is how mine currently appears:
[image: My ht]

Comment: What are the contents of `$mile2[ "milestones"]` ?

Comment: The following is what is contained in 1 number value `$mile2['milestones][number value from 0 upwards depending on result]['string'] $mile2['milestones][number value from 0 upwards depending on result]['string'] $mile2['milestones][number value from 0 upwards depending on result]['datetime']`

Answer (score 0):

The first Problem I see in your code is that `date` is declared `d ate` even though im not shure if that is actually the problem. I suggest to `var_dump()` the contents of your array to rule out the possibility of sending in false data to your frontend.

Additionally you can make shure the javascript ist loaded after the DOM is done loading by using jQuery $(function()) as the javascript might trigger before your html is fully loaded.

*Here some optimized code:*

```
<ol>
<?php foreach ($mile2["milestones"] as $key => $value) : ?>
    <?php if ($key != 0): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#0" 
               data-date="<?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($value['start_time']['date'])); ?>"
            ><?= date('d M', strtotime($value['start_time']['date'])); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#0" 
               data-date="<?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($value['start_time']['date'])); ?>" 
               class="selected"
            ><?= date('d M', strtotime($value['start_time']['date'])); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: The spaces were an error caused by pasting into Stack Overflow, I'm not sure how, but I do not have those spaces in my code. Sadly your code doesn't have any change. I have noticed that this transform: scaleX(1.03137); should be transform: scaleX(0.0762977); It's bizarre as to why.